# How do I cut internet but connect X server for systemd-nspawned program

Tags: xorg, systemd-nspawn

I'm setting my Archlinux to run programs on Ubuntu Natty via `systemd-nspawn`.

Currently I start the session with `--setenv=DISPLAY=:0 --bind=/dev -a su -l (user) -c xfce4-panel`.

I'm trying to disable the internet for the guest because of security concerns, but when I give `--private-network` it fails to connect to xorg on the host.

Is there any way to solve it?